# Electromotor ageing effects

Tags: motor

I found with search for `electromotor ageing effects site:electronics.stackexchange.com` only [DC Motor Friction Torque](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/281311/dc-motor-friction-torque), saying:

> In general, motor frictional losses are ignored - if you have to take
>   them into account you're working too close to the edge.

Relative of mine said washing machine started to work poorly (worse water removal) and gave hypothesis that the motor started to work worse. As I understand engineering of electric motor, the power cannot decrease from ageing of wires etc, motor just fails completely. If post noted above is correct, then ageing of bearings cannot be the problem too. I am not sure about degradation of brushes (if motor is not brushless).

Can electric motor power/torque decrease with age to any practical significance degree?

Comment: It's bad bearings. When they go bad, the account for a LOT of losses.  When they are working well then their losses are minimal.

Comment: You need to be certain of the problem description - "worse water removal" MAY be due to a failing water pump - and sometimes is dues to material trapped in the pump. As Aaron says - failed motor bearings can lead to major mechanical losses.

Comment: If the bearings are causing significant friction, then they will quickly fail completely - graunching noise, stopped rotation, smoke. It's possible for a pump to get clagged-up inside so it doesn't pump anywhere near as quickly, see if you can dismantle and clean.

Comment: @Neil_UK, thank you!